# Fastest/Most optimal way to lookup a sequence of letters in a dictionary written in file

Tags: python, string, file, dictionary, permutation

I have a sequence of letters, not necessarily a word. I also have a file containing about 6000 words. I have to decide whether any rearrangement of the sequence of letters make a word that is in the file.

What would be the fastest/optimal way to do this? What if I can't load the whole file in memory? What if I can?

I thought of a solution that is O(N^2). Of course matching individual words won't have as much effect as the number of words. But anyways, it could be called a O(n^2), isn't it? Reading each line from file and checking whether the given sequence and the line's lengths are equal. If yes, then counting the occurrences of each character and matching them.

```
matched_words = []
with open('words.txt') as file:
for line in file:
    if len(line.strip()) == len(letters) and 
      Counter(line.strip()) == Counter(letters):
        matched_words.append(line.strip())
return matched_words
```

This works, but is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Can you really not load 6000 words into memory? Note also that to find anagrams you can using sorting, e.g. `sorted('dog') == sorted('god')`.

Comment: Is this a one off, or are you going to do this many times ... in the next year? month? day? millisecond?
Also, what will vary? Will it be the sequence of letters, or the file containing a large number of words? As @jonsharpe says you could sort all the words.

Comment: What is `Counter` here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i could load the whole file. but what if i couldn't? i'm looking for the relative advantages and disadvantages. in case of anagrams, it's still at least nlog(n) right? so for n words in dictionary, n * nlog(n) is still O(n^2). am i correct?

@ quamrana i didn't understand your question. sorry

@ JacobIRR Counter is a function from collections library

Comment: Well, what if? Why don't you solve the problem you actually have, rather than trying to find solutions to others?

Comment: ya, that's a good point. i was just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

For each word in the file, you can check `sorted(query)==sorted(word)`. The complexity would be O(nklogk) where n is the number of words and k is the length of the word.
If you need to look up multiple queries, you can do some pre computation to make it faster. you can sort each word in the file, and load them into a set in-memory and test for set membership. If you need to find the actual words that are rearrangements of the given sequence of characters, load into a dict{sorted_form: } and lookup each query.
You can also precompute a trie of sorted forms and store the dictionary words in the trie nodes. Given a query word of size k, sort the word O(klogk) and lookup into the trie in O(k) to give a complexity per lookup of O(k^2*logk)

Comment: sorting is still O(nlogn) right? Counting occurrences of individual characters is O(n). isn't it better than sorting? btw, the words in the dictionary are already essentially sorted.

Comment: Please don't mix up the number of words (n) and the length per word (k). Assuming that n>>k is the case here, sorting each word is klogk can be removed like a constant factor and treat O(nklogk) as O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is on the right track. We can clean this up by eliminating extra work as follows.

```
from collections import Counter
def gen_matches(target, filepath):
    target_count = Counter(target)
    target_len = len(target)
    with open(filepath) as file:
        for line in file:
            word = line.strip()
            if len(word) == target_len and Counter(word) == target_count:
                yield word
```

As you can see these are minimal changes. We can save some extra effort by only calling `Counter()` and `len()` on our target once, and by assigning the output of line.strip() so that we don't have to repeat the function call.

This avoids loading the entire file in memory. It is also O(n), assuming our constant factor k (the length of the average word) is much smaller than the number of words. This is asymptotically faster in a computer-science sense than comparing `sorted(word)` and `sorted(target)`; however, in practice, comparing the sorted words may be faster, since python's implementation of `sorted()` is very fast indeed.

You might want to try timing both approaches! :)